# Insert into select from

Tags: mysql, insert, multiple-select

I have following two tables:

```
chat_users:      chat_friends:
+-----+------+   +------+--------+
| uid | name |   | user | friend |
+-----+------+   +------+--------+
|   1 | foo  |   |    1 |      2 |
|   2 | bar  |   +------+--------+
+-----+------+
```

I want to select two `uid`'s from `chat_users` by `name` and insert them as a pair into `chat_friends` as shown in my example. I don't know, how I can make this work. Is this kind of query possible without php and/or temporary tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify 2 names and JOIN chat_users with itself and see if the 2 names matches and insert like below

```
insert into chat_friends(user,friend)
select cu1.uid,cu2.uid
from chat_users cu1 JOIN chat_users cu2
where cu1.name = 'foo'
  and cu2.name = 'bar';
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95a9b4/1/0)

alternately you can just individually select the uid of each name as below too if you prefer.

```
insert into chat_friends(user,friend)
select (select uid from chat_users where name = 'foo'),
       (select uid from chat_users where name = 'bar');
```

Comment: Thank you :) I used JOIN only in connection with INNER or OUTER and forgot completely that I can use it this way too.